# redefine R's list item lookup so key errors can be produced?

Tags: r

Getting an element from an R list by name using "$" or "[[" returns "NULL" when the named element isn't in the list. I'd prefer that it produce an error, since this would make debugging a lot easier. Is there a way to redefine these operators so that I get the errors I want?

Note that "get" has the behavior I'd like, but using "get" instead of "$" everywhere would make my code a bit harder to read.

```
> myList <- list(a=5)
> myList
$a
[1] 5

> myList$b
NULL
> myList[["b"]]
NULL
> get("b", myList)
Error in get("b", myList) : object 'b' not found
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure this is something you *should*  do, but it is something you *can* do. In general, you can put functions in your environment that mask the builtins and they'll get used appropriately, you just need to use backquotes.

```
`$` <- function(x,y) {
  S <- as.character(sys.call()[3]);
  a <- eval(substitute(.Primitive("$")(x, S)));
  if(!is.null(a)) a else stop("Not Found"); 
}

R>sleep$extra
 [1]  0.7 -1.6 -0.2 -1.2 -0.1  3.4  3.7  0.8  0.0  2.0  1.9  0.8  1.1  0.1 -0.1  4.4  5.5  1.6  4.6  3.4
R>sleep$CERA
Error in sleep$CERA : Not Found
```

Comment: Why do you use `sys.call()[3]`? Is not the same than `sys.call()`?  
It would be possible then to change ``$`` to `get` function, so to avoid this new function?

Comment: `sys.call()[3]` is the third element of the sys.call(), which is the name of the element. in my examples, `sleep$extra` has a sys.call() of `c(\`$\`, sleep, extra)`

Comment: Yes, of course, but then it is not general, and about changing the `$` function by `get`?

Comment: Is this what you are asking about: 
` \`$\` <- get; sleep$extra;` 

That throws an error:
    `Error in sleep$extra : object 'extra' not found`

Comment: Yes he pointed out that get, does what he want, so redefining $ with get will not work?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43184/discussion-between-neal-fultz-and-llopis)

Comment: I think @Llopis is talking about something like `"$" <- function(where, what) get(deparse(substitute(what)), where)`